# With fadein fadeout in cocos2d-x, the children is not synchronous(fadein fadeout)

Tags: cocos2d-x, parent, fadein, fadeout, children

in cocos2d-x, you can use "setCascadeOpacityEnabled" to synchronize the parent and children fadein and fadeout. However "setCascadeOpacityEnabled" just make the parent and children fadeout and fadein, the children's children is not set.

if you wanna the all node of a parent synchronize fadein and fadeout, you must setCascadeOpacityEnabled all node with children "true".

Comment: Can you clarify what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I got the answer, and I just took it down.